# Чем воспользоваться для длинной арифметики?

Tags: c++, поиск-библиотек, длинная-арифметика

Хочется иметь что-то очень длинное целое, но при этом простое. При том, что работаю на VC++ (сейчас 2017).

GMP под Windows, как я понял, заставиить работать нельзя, если только не работать с gcc.

Нашел MPIR, который вроде должен скомпилиться под VC++ 2017, но никак не могу это сделать - все время какие-то ошибки (типа

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: не удается открыть входной файл "x64\Release\mpn\add_err1_n.obj"
EXEC : error : 'output_params.bat' not found
```

Слышал, что вроде бы в Boost есть такая функциональность - multiprecision без использования GMP или еще что, чисто свое.

Скорость мне, конечно, хочется, но еще больше хочется отсутствия проблем при сборках и пересборках при выходе новой версии. Поэтому помогите с ответом на один из вопросов:

1. Как правильно скомпилировать под VC++ MPIR [отсюда](http://mpir.org/mpir-3.0.0.zip) - нужны варианты для 32 и 64 бит, без DLL (обычная LIB).
2. Или, если есть такой Boost, который не зависит от внешних библиотек - то как именно его найти и использовать? То, что я находил, хотело GMP. И если есть - что именно качать и ставить, чтоб не весь Boost, а только вот этот кусочек - по минимуму?
3. Если есть еще какой-то вариант попроще, но надежный - подскажите.

В первую очередь интересует целочисленная арифметика, с плавающей точкой - конечно, приятный бонус, но не такой уж и обязательный.

Comment: Так напиши сам её. Я так и сделал не очень эффективно но для rsa хватает.

Comment: у boost::multiprecision есть несколько backend'ов. Да, gmp_int зависит от gmp, а cpp_int — чистая плюсовая шаблонная реализация в хедерах.

Comment: @Fat-Zer А не подскажете, как именно скачать и использовать *только её* - я с бустом никогда не работал?

Comment: @Mikhailo не подскажу, а я с msvc с детства не работал ;)...

Comment: в openssl есть [BIGNUM](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Bn(3))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку я в основном тоже на VC++ сижу...

Самое мелкое, с чем сталкивался - [`BigInt`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/). Но, откровенно говоря, только сталкивался - скомпилировалось, но даже разбираться не стал.

В свое время для Open Watcom использовал [MAPM](https://github.com/LuaDist/mapm), сделав для него обертку в виде класса С++. Когда-то мне писали о каких-то его багах при инициализации из строки, но за давностью лет не помню, что именно, ну, а на нескольких проектах сравнение с boost показало, что результаты дает одинаковые. Но несколько медленнее...

С boost'ом, откровенно говоря, не стал мучиться - развернул его 120 мегабайт (эх, какой в 1991 году у меня был крутой винт на машине - 120 мегабайт... но это так, ностальгическое отступление :)) и не стал заморачиваться выдиранием нужного. Тем более что там все повязано так, что развязать этот узел слишком морочливо. Решил, что когда чего-то не хватит - тогда и буду разбираться :) Пока вполне хватало

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
using large = boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;
```

после чего просто работал с `large` как обычным `int` - у меня нет особо специфичных задач, чтоб разбираться со всеми его типами и возможностями. Наверняка я забиваю гвозди микроскопом, но...

Только вот с VC++ 2017 даже последний boost не умеет корректно работать. Если тут есть специалисты - пусть скажут, если я неправ, но я просто заткнул ему рот с помощью

```
#define  BOOST_CONFIG_SUPPRESS_OUTDATED_MESSAGE
#define  _SILENCE_CXX17_OLD_ALLOCATOR_MEMBERS_DEPRECATION_WARNING
```

Не претендую на полноту ответа ни в малейшей мере. Так, заметки из собственной практики.

Answer (score 0):

сделайте такой файлик
msvc/output_params.bat

```
(set ldir=lib_mpir_gc\)   
(set libr=lib) 
(set plat=x64) 
(set conf=Debug)
```